# publish new method to existing web site

Tags: web-services, iis

Hi I have web service deployed to IIS I added new method to source code ; I want this new method added to the deployed web site; I need  guide to accomplish this

Comment: If you want continuous integration and deployment, you have to utilize other tools than merely IIS. Asking "step by step guide" is asking others to solve the challenge for you (for free), so such would be downvoted, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: i want  post deleted

Comment: You should be able to delete by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some times refresh in IIS will be sufficient....